# Выделение столбца со всеми ячейками

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Пишу [такое дело](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/9yODl).

Хочется сделать подсветку столбца с продуктом, ну как-то рамочку добавить чтобы элемент выделялся из общей таблицы, подсветку или тень, в примере нету, но пытался прикрутить таким способом выделение, в css добавил

```
.pricing-hover {
  background-color: #606060;
}
```

в html дописал id чтобы проще было найти таблицу внутри сменив:

```
<div class="membership-pricing-table">
```

на

```
<div id="wedding-prices" class="membership-pricing-table">
```

в js написал это:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#wedding-prices table');
    table.delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            var el = $(this);
            pos = el.index();
            el.parent().find("th, td").addClass("pricing-hover");
            table.filter(":nth-child(" + (pos+1) + ")").addClass("pricing-hover");
        }
        else {
          table.find("th, td").removeClass("pricing-hover");
        }
    });

});
```

Не уверен, что оно подсветит прямо весь столбец, но по крайней мере оно добавляет каким-то `td` класс `hover`. Но цвет выделения не меняется, получается, что внешний класс из css `.membership-pricing-table table td {...}` почему-то переопределяет цвет `background`, хотя в css он прописан раньше чем `pricing-hover`.

Может индивидуальным `td` нельзя задавать `background` прямо в них?
Где скрылся подводный камень?
Есть ли какое-то решение выделение столбца с ячейками?

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('.table-responsive table');
    table.delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
      if (e.type == 'mouseover') {

        var el = $(this);
        tdI = el.index();

        var rows = table.find('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          $(rows[i]).find('td').eq(tdI).addClass("pricing-hover");
        }
      } else {
        table.find("th, td").removeClass("pricing-hover");
      }
    });

  });
```

```css
.membership-pricing-table {
  width: 920px
}
.membership-pricing-table table .icon-no,
.membership-pricing-table table .icon-yes {
  font-size: 22px
}
.membership-pricing-table table .icon-no {
  color: #a93717
}
.membership-pricing-table table .icon-yes {
  color: #209e61
}
.membership-pricing-table table .plan-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  padding: 25px 0
}
.membership-pricing-table table .plan-header-free {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #555
}
.membership-pricing-table table .plan-header-blue {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61a1d1;
  border-color: #3989c6
}
.membership-pricing-table table .plan-header-standard {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9317;
  border-color: #e37900
}
.membership-pricing-table table td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset
}
.membership-pricing-table table,
.membership-pricing-table table td {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr td:first-child {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: right;
  width: 24%
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr td:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #FFF
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child td,
.membership-pricing-table table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #e2e2e2
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child th .pricing-plan-name {
  font-size: 22px
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child th .pricing-plan-price {
  line-height: 35px
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child th .pricing-plan-price>sup {
  font-size: 45%
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child th .pricing-plan-price>span {
  font-size: 30%
}
.membership-pricing-table table tr:first-child th .pricing-plan-period {
  margin-top: -7px;
  font-size: 25%
}
.membership-pricing-table table .header-plan-inner {
  position: relative
}
.membership-pricing-table table .recommended-plan-ribbon {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #dc3b5d;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 11px!important;
  font-weight: 500;
  left: -6px;
  top: -22px;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px #c2284c inset;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px #c2284c inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px #c2284c
}
.membership-pricing-table table .recommended-plan-ribbon:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #c2284c transparent;
  border-width: 6px 0 0 6px;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 90
}
.membership-pricing-table table .recommended-plan-ribbon:after {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #c2284c transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 90
}
.membership-pricing-table table .plan-head {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
  border: 1px solid #cf7300;
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: -1px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: none
}
.pricing-hover {
  background-color: #606060 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div class="membership-pricing-table">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th class="plan-header plan-header-free">
            <div class="pricing-plan-name">TFP</div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-price">
              10<span>у.е.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-period">срок: 2-3 месяца</div>
          </th>
          <th class="plan-header plan-header-blue">
            <div class="pricing-plan-name">Микро</div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-price">
              50<span>у.е.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
          </th>
          <th class="plan-header plan-header-blue">
            <div class="pricing-plan-name">Мини</div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-price">
              100<span>у.е.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-period">срок: 2 месяца</div>
          </th>
          <th class="plan-header plan-header-standard">
            <div class="header-plan-inner">
              <!--<span class="plan-head"> </span>-->
              <span class="recommended-plan-ribbon">Рекомендуется</span>
              <div class="pricing-plan-name">Стандарт</div>
              <div class="pricing-plan-price">
                220<span>у.е.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-plan-period">срок: 1,5 месяца</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="plan-header plan-header-blue">
            <div class="pricing-plan-name">Макси</div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-price">
              300<span>у.е.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-period">срок: 1 месяц</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>

          <td class="action-header">
            <a class="btn btn-info">
                            Предложить
                        </a>
          </td>
          <td class="action-header">
            <a class="btn btn-info">
                            Предложить
                        </a>
          </td>
          <td class="action-header">
            <a class="btn btn-success">
                            Заказать
                        </a>
          </td>
          <td class="action-header">
            <a class="btn btn-success">
                            Заказать
                        </a>
          </td>
          <td class="action-header">
            <a class="btn btn-success">
                            Заказать
                        </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Съёмка сборов:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Съёмка ЗАГЗа:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Съёмка прогулки:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Съёмка до первого танца:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Съёмка до снятия фаты:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Весь отснятый материал:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Все отснятые фото с корррекцией:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Фото на DVD диске:</td>
          <td><span class="icon-no glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
          <td><span class="icon-yes glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Продолжительность:</td>
          <td>2-6 часа</td>
          <td>2-4</td>
          <td>4-6</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>10-12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Фотографий:</td>
          <td>35-50</td>
          <td>20-40</td>
          <td>100-150</td>
          <td>250-350</td>
          <td>500-600</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2** через filter()

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('.table-responsive table');
        table.delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
            if (e.type == 'mouseover') {

                var el = $(this);
                tdI = el.index() + 1;
                table.find('tr td').filter(":nth-child(" + tdI + ")").addClass("pricing-hover");

            } else {
                table.find("td").removeClass("pricing-hover");
            }
        });

    });
```